# Combobox_OnLeave Fires Before ComboBox_SelectedValueChange

Tags: winforms, combobox

I have a comboBox with the following Properties:

```
AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend;
AutoCompleteSource = ListItems;
DropDownStyle = DropDown;
```

in the above properties, it is obviously that i set my `DropdownStyle` into `Dropdown` to be able the user to type into the `combobox` for them to search in the list item.

in the worst case scenario, the user may type unmatched items in the `combobox` and then leave it (no `selectedValue` were selected since the user leave the `comboBox`)

below is my workaround :

```
private void cbOPRecName_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (cbOPRecName.Text != "" && cbOPRecName.SelectedValue == null)
      cbOPRecName.Text = "";
}
```

But the Problem is, whenever `cbOPRecName_Leave` fires, `cbOPRecName.Text` has no value/Text even there has a type text in the `comboBox`, also, as i observed it can be evaluated after `cbOPRecName_Leave` fires (I've noticed it on my `cbOPRecName_SelectedValueChange`).

Any advice?

Comment: I can't reproduce your scenario. Have you tried with a small sample that exibits this behavior?

Comment: Hi Steve, as far as my concern, the problem is that in the Leave event of combobox, the ComboBox.SelectedValue has no value (even if it has) and i've notice that it will having a value after leaving the comboBox (Since i have a SelectedValueChange event and fires after leave event)